Sending telegram messages via madelineProto does not work
I try to send a message to a telegram supergroup in two ways:
tinker(working method):
> $api = new danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
> $api->start();
> $api->sendMessage(peer: -1002056889962, message: 'TEST test <br /> TEST test', parseMode: danog\MadelineProto\ParseMode::HTML, replyToMsgId: 11164, topMsgId: 11164);

Console command launched in scheduler(not working method):
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\MailingStatusEnum;
use App\Models\Mailing;
use App\Models\TelegramGroup;
use App\Models\TelegramUser;
use App\Models\Topic;
use danog\MadelineProto\API;
use danog\MadelineProto\LocalFile;
use danog\MadelineProto\ParseMode;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Throwable;

class SendMailingsCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'app:send-mailings-command';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'check and send mailings';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $lockFile = '/tmp/telegram_bot_mailing.lock';
        $hour = now()->hour;
        $minute = now()->minute;
        $second = now()->second;
        $startTime = "startTime $hour:$minute:$second:";

        if (file_exists($lockFile)) {
            exit();
        }

        file_put_contents($lockFile, 'running');

        if (Mailing::query()->where('status', MailingStatusEnum::PROCESSING)->count() > 0) {
            return;
        }

        $madelineProto = new API('session.madeline');

        $mailing = Mailing::query()
            ->where('status', MailingStatusEnum::NEW)
            ->first();

        if (!$mailing) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            $mailing->update(['status' => MailingStatusEnum::PROCESSING]);

            foreach ($mailing->telegram_group_ids as $telegramGroupId) {
                $group = TelegramGroup::query()->find($telegramGroupId);

                $text = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $mailing->text) . '<br /><br />';

                $group
                    ->usersWithRoles()
                    ->whereIn('role_id', $mailing->role_ids)
                    ->each(function (TelegramUser $telegramUser) use (&$text) {
                        $text .= $telegramUser->telegram_tag ? ' @'.$telegramUser->telegram_tag : " <a href='tg://user?id={$telegramUser->id}'>$telegramUser->name</a>";
                    });
                $media = [];

                $mediaFiles = $mailing->getMedia();

                foreach ($mediaFiles as $index => $mediaFile) {
                    if ($file = $this->handleFile($mediaFile, $index, $text, $mediaFiles->count())) {
                        logger('file', [$file]);
                        $media[] = $file;
                    }
                }



                $mailing->update([
                    'media_files' => $media
                ]);

                $resultMailing = null;

                $group
                    ->topics()
                    ->whereIn('name', $mailing->topic_ids)
                    ->each(function(Topic $topic) use ($media, $madelineProto, $group, $text, $startTime) {
                        $resultMailing = count($media) === 0
                            ? $madelineProto
                                ->sendMessage(
                                    peer: $group->telegram_id,
                                    message: $text,
                                    parseMode: ParseMode::HTML,
                                    replyToMsgId: $topic->topic_id,
                                    topMsgId: $topic->topic_id,
                                )
                            : $madelineProto
                                ->messages
                                ->sendMultiMedia(
                                    peer: $group->telegram_id,
                                    reply_to_msg_id: $topic->topic_id,
                                    top_msg_id: $topic->topic_id,
                                    multi_media: $media,
                                );
                        logger()
                            ->channel('mailing_sending_log')
                            ->info("$startTime sending mailing", ['resultMailing' => $resultMailing, 'group' => $group]);
                    });

            }

            $mailing->update(['status' => MailingStatusEnum::SENDED]);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            logger()
                ->channel('mailing_sending_log')
                ->info("$startTime ошибка рассылки", ['error' => $e, 'mailing' => $mailing]);
            $mailing->update([
                'status' => MailingStatusEnum::FAILED,
                'error' => [$e],
            ]);
        }

        unlink($lockFile);
    }

    protected function handleFile($mediaFile, int $index, string $text, $count): array|null
    {
        $filePath = $mediaFile->getPath();
        $mimeType = mime_content_type($filePath);

        return [
            '_' => 'inputSingleMedia',
            'media' => [
                '_' => 'inputMediaUploadedDocument',
                'force_file' => true,
                'file' => new LocalFile($filePath),
                'mime_type' => $mimeType,
                'attributes' => [
                    ['_' => 'documentAttributeFilename', 'file_name' => basename($filePath)]
                ]
            ],
            'message' => $index === $count - 1 ? $text : '',
            'parse_mode' => ParseMode::HTML,
        ];
    }
}

As a result, when sending a message through Tinker, it is sent perfectly, but if I use the console command called by the scheduler, I get the error: This peer is not present in the internal peer database
I've already tried a lot, although when I noticed that everything works through the tinker, but not through the scheduler, now I can't get it out of my head and I don't know where to go next
-------
ADDITION:
Not in all cases when working with the scheduler I get an error, but here is one of the rather strange cases that I don’t know how to solve

this error means you have tried sending a message to a peer that does not exist or is not present in MadelineProto’s internal peer database: in fact, @dd is not a valid telegram username.
